# highcharts, toggle a category?

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to hide and show categories on a stacked column chart. So I've got something like this:

```
|  :             :
|  \         :   :   
|  \    :    :   :
|  \    \    :   \
|  \    \    \   \   : 
------------------------
   A    B    C   D   E
```

A chart with two series (`\` and `:`) and five categories. I know how to toggle either `\` or `:`, but how do I toggle `A` or `B` or `C` or `D` or `E`? In my experiments so far, the only thing I've come up with is redrawing the whole chart and leaving out any categories that I want hidden. Is there another option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there isn't a built-in way to do this. It's worth posting this question on the [Highcharts forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=9) if you haven't already. I had a somewhat similar problem where I wanted to have different views of the x-axis which was dates without having to make people use the built-in zoom via mouse tool. I ended up making a toggle button on the page which redraws the graph.

Comment: I've posted there, thanks. Yeah, I've already built the redraw functionality. It wasn't as bad as I feared.... :)